Stability of dynamical system where part of the state goes to zero
Consider the following dynamical system:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x_1 + g_1(x_1,x_2)\\
\dot{x}_2 &= g_2(x_2)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_2\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $g_2(x_2)$ is such that $x_2$ always converges to $0$ (e.g., $g_2(x_2) = -x_2$) and $g(x_1,x_2)$ is a non-linear term such that $g(x_1,0) = 0$. Additionally, let the system be such that its trajectories $(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ are bounded (in my case, I can show that all balls $B_r=\{(x_1,x_2): \lVert x_1\rVert^2 + \lVert x_2\rVert^2 = r\}$ are positively invariant if $r$ is greater than some value $M\in\mathbb{R}_+$).
I can easily prove that the origin is asymptotically stable by linearizing around the origin. Moreover, I intuitively expect the system to be globally stable, since $x_2\rightarrow 0$ regardless of $x_1$ and the trajectories cannot run off to infinity. Still, I wasn't able to prove it. My attempts to find a suitable Lyapunov function have been unfruitful, and honestly I don't know any another approach than Lyapunov/LaSalle methods to prove global stability.
Am I missing something obvious here? What are other methods/strategies that I could use to tackle this problem? Thanks!

What do you mean by ``$g(x_1,x_2)$ is a non-linear term such that the trajectories are bounded''?, trajectories of which systems? $\dot x_1=g(x_1,x_2)$ for arbitrary $x_2\in \mathbb{R}$? If this is the case, bounded uniformly on $x_2$? Please clarify!

@MatteoDR What I meant is that all trajectories $(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ are bounded, in the sense that if I take a ball $B_r={(x_1,x_2): \lVert x_1\lVert^2+\lVert x_2\lVert^2=r}$, then it is positively invariant for the system for all $r>M$, with $M$ being "big enough". Thanks for the question, I'll edit my post for clarity.

Another strategy which comes in my mind to show stability is the use of contraction theory see e.g. https://fbullo.github.io/ctds/

Thanks for the clarifications. I think you can apply the results concerning cascade systems, in particular result based on ISS (input-to-state-stability) concept. I can refer to Lemma 4.6 and Lemma 4.7 in the book ''Non-Linear Systems" (third edition), H.K. Khalil.
This will require some additional properties on the function $g_1$, but maybe it can help.

@MatteoDR Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

You will need the additional assumption that $g_1$ is bounded, otherwise ISS won't work.
